# How could Korematsu be overturned?

Tags: us-supreme-court, precedent

The US Supreme Court Case [Korematsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korematsu_v._United_States) (1944) ruled that the internment of American citizens of Japanese ancestry was legal out of concern for national security.  This case is now generally regarded as a mistake, even though it has never been revisited or overturned.

Short of a new case involving the mass incarceration of another group of citizens based on their national origin, is there a legal means to have the precedent re-visited and overturned?  Are we effectively stuck with this decision remaining as case law that can be cited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On June 26, 2018, the Supreme Court effectively overturned Korematsu by issuing a majority decision on another case<sup>[**1**]</sup>.

Chief Justice Roberts wrote in the decision of *Hawaii v. Trump*:
*(commonly known as the Third Travel Ban)*

> “The forcible relocation of U.S. citizens to concentration camps,
>   solely and explicitly on the basis of race, is objectively unlawful
>   and outside the scope of presidential authority,”

This is now a majority decision, more recent than Korematsu, which can be cited in future cases.

<sup>**1**</sup> https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/26/us/korematsu-supreme-court-ruling.html

Answer (score 2):

The decision is not “on the books”: case law is not statute law.

The precedent stays and remains binding unless and until a case arises where the SCOTUS reverses it or Congress writes a law that bans mass incarceration. Assuming the underlying law on which the decision rested is still in existence and enforced of course.

The primary purpose of the judicial arm of government is not to interpret laws or set precedents; it is to decide disputes. Interpreting law and setting precedent is incidental to that primary purpose. Absent a dispute, the judiciary does not get engaged.

Given that the general consensus of legal opinion (what might be called the [vibe](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wJuXIq7OazQ)) is that the precedent *would* be reversed it is unlikely that the administrative branch would rely on the precedent. Therefore they wouldn’t mass incarcerate and no dispute will arise.

Comment: A statute wouldn't overturn  Korematsu, it would just provide more protections that the constitution requires. The US AG could issue an opinion claiming that Korematsu is no longer good law which would bind the U.S. government, but that could be overturned by a later AG. And, if the US doesn't repeat Korematsu, there might never be a chance to litigate it to overturn the precedent. A constitutional amendment could overrule Korematsu, however.

Comment: @ohwilleke does the court's opinion in Hawaii v. Trump actually overturn the precedent as many are saying?  The issues decided in the cases do not seem particularly similar; it just seems that the court has repudiated *Korematsu* "by the way."

Comment: @phoog *Korematu* is for all practical purposes no longer good law, even if the holding is arguably dicta. Exactly why *Hawaii v. Trump* is not *Korematu*, i.e. which distinction is the one that matters, still isn't entirely clear.